# SQL: Update existing value if exists. Use parameterized query (?)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the following working code:

```
def insert_into_conversationid_table(connection:sqlite3.Connection, values_:list((str, str, int))) -> None:
    insert_into_conversation = """
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO
        conversationid_table (id, subject, finish)
    VALUES
        (?, ?, ?)
    """
    execute_query_with_params(connection, insert_into_conversation, values_)
    pass
```

ID is the unique column. This code only inserts new data and ignores it if the same ID exists in the DB.
I use Python and library sqlite3.

Now I would like to change the above code so that instead of ignoring, it should update the column `finish`. My following code doesn't work:

```
def insert_into_conversationid_table(connection:sqlite3.Connection, values_:list((str, str, int))) -> None:
    insert_into_conversation = """
    INSERT INTO
        conversationid_table (id, subject, finish)
    VALUES
        (?1, ?2, ?3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        finish = ?3
    """
    execute_query_with_params(connection, insert_into_conversation, values_)
    pass
```

The problem is I believe on line `finish = ?3`.
I would like to preserve the parameterized query (?) if possible.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

You can use SQLite's [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) and the `EXCLUDED` table qualifier for the value of the column `finish`:

```
insert_into_conversation = """
INSERT INTO conversationid_table(id, subject, finish) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET finish = EXCLUDED.finish
"""
execute_query_with_params(connection, insert_into_conversation, values_)
```

Here, `EXCLUDED.finish` refers to the value of `finish` that would have been inserted but failed because of a unique constraint violation.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be able to use non named parameters here:

```py
sql = """
INSERT INTO conversationid_table (id, subject, finish)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE finish = ?"""
cursor.execute(sql, (param1, param2, param3, param3,))  -- param3 is bound twice
```

There might be some performance drawback to the above, as it requires you to bind the same `param3` to the statement twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a better solution to avoid the param3 to be bounded twice? Is there something equivalent to "?3" in SQL?

Comment: I don't know if such an API exists.  In any case, it should be a very small performance penalty to use what I suggested above.  If you have many other very large statements with this caveat, then maybe do more research.

Comment: I meant without using any API and just by using SQL command. I did my research and didn't find any. Well I am not SQL-expert but think SQL should be able to handle that... Thank you again for your code above.